# what are relationship between between azure resource management(manager) and control plane?

Tags: azure

> **Control plane**: All requests for control plane operations are sent to the **Azure Resource Manager URL**. That URL varies by the Azure environment.

And from image [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/custom-providers/overview), it seems that the control plane and Azure Resource Manager are the same things.  What are the differences between them?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### ARM vs ASM

**Azure Resource Manger** (ARM) is one of two Deployment models in Azure, the other is **Azure Service Manager** (ASM), now called ***Classic***.  These models are considered the Control plane.  You can learn more about the different models here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/deployment-models

### Azure control plane and data plane

Azure operations can be divided into two categories - control plane and data plane. You use the control plane to manage resources in your subscription. You use the data plane to use capabilities exposed by your instance of a resource type.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [Ken W MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4800789/ken-w-msft), Here is the
answer from [Azure Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/migration-classic-resource-manager-faq).

> What is Azure Service Manager and what does it mean by classic?
>
> The word "classic" in IaaS VM (classic) refers to VMs managed by Azure Service Manager (ASM). Azure Service Manager (ASM) is **the old control plane** of Azure responsible for creating, managing, deleting VMs and performing other control plane operations.
>
> What is Azure Resource Manager?
>
> Azure Resource Manager is the latest control plane of Azure responsible for creating, managing, deleting VMs and performing other control plane operations.